# Pleine : bien mangé ou enceinte?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Tout au long de mes études, on m'a donné des traductions et des explications contradictoires sur comment dire « I'm full ». Parfois, mes enseignant-e-s m'ont dit que c'est « J'ai bien mangé » ou « J'ai trop mangé », dépendamment sur le sentiment qu'on veut transmettre, mais ils étaient résolus qu'on ne dit jamais « j'ai plein-e ». Ils m'ont expliqué que c'est une autre façon de dire « Je suis enceinte », surtout si l'on est fille ou femme.

Pourtant, les autres m'ont dit que « Je suis pleine » est compris dans le sens « I'm full »" parce que « pleine » veut dire « enceinte » seulement si l'on parle d'un animal. **Donc, quelle est la bonne réponse? Pourquoi existe-t-il ces réponses contradictoires?**

Je viens de découvrir maintenant qu'on peut aussi dire « rassasié-e ».

Answer (score 7):

En France, « je suis plein » risque de ne pas être compris s'il s'agit de signifier que l'on a assez mangé. C'est une expression qui peut aussi être considérée comme déplacée, voire grossière car « être plein » signifie en langage familier que l'on a bu trop d'alcool, pas que l'on a trop mangé (même si [ce sens est attesté au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plein)).

On dira donc:

- Je suis rassasié ou repu. (registe soutenu)
- J'ai bien mangé
- J'ai trop mangé (Je ne peux plus manger, je n'ai plus faim).

S'il s'agit d'une femme, cette expression qui manque terriblement d'élégance pourra aussi faire sourire car elle peut sous-entendre qu'elle se considère comme un animal en gestation.

Il m'arrive cependant de dire pour plaisanter « je suis plein » mais uniquement à des interlocuteurs qui connaissent suffisamment l'anglais pour comprendre ce que je veux dire.

Comment: To add (not to contradict): the TLF's [etymology](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/plein) mentions it in the sense of « empli de nourriture » (2 - d) *and* « enceinte » (6 - c) from the 13th century, but from the examples there's not quite enough context to see whether that meaning was packed into an unqualified « plein » or whether « plein » could simply be used in sentences with that meaning (it gives « yvre et plenne de vin » for the food case). In any case, seconded this answer that nothing I've learned suggests « plein » on its own meaning "full" as we mean in English.

Comment: "Je suis plein" dans le sens de "j'ai trop mangé" me paraît totalement compréhensible dans le contexte adéquat (exemple : on te propose un troisième dessert au repas de Noël).

Comment: @LukeSawczak Voir aussi au [DMF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/plein?idf=dmfXdXrmXpebb;str=0); l'exemple ds. la version Ms. Fr. 169 du [_Livre de la chasse_](http://www.e-codices.unifr.ch/fr/bge/fr0169/83v/0/Sequence-108), 2e col. dernier 1/3, _trop plains_ (des loups).

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Oui, ce sera compris mais, au moins en France, sera le plus souvent considéré comme une expression vulgaire ou alors à prendre au deuxième degré.

Comment: Oui je suis d'accord, ce n'est pas idiomatique et plutôt comique ou vulgaire.

Answer (score 6):

Il est possible que les réponses soient contradictoires puisque l'expression « être plein » a une signification différente selon les régions.

Comme l'indique [la réponse de jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/25651/217), l'expression n'est pas utilisée en France pour indiquer la satiété et peut être mal reçue.

Pourtant, de l'autre côté de l'Atlantique, au Canada, l'expression est couramment utilisé pour signifier que l'on a effectivement bien mangé, voire trop mangé. Il s'agit en fait de la première chose, peut-être même la seule, à laquelle la majorité des gens penseront. Il est difficile de dire s'il s'agit d'un anglicisme ou d'une expression vieillie toujours vivante au Québec.

Selon l'endroit où vous vous trouvez, il sera prudent de garder cette différence à l'esprit.

Comment: C'est bien intéressant, merci. C'est clair que c'est usuel au Qc., je ne sais pas si c'est fam./pop. Mais je ne l'ai pas trouvé au fameux [_Glossaire_](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) (1930) alors qu'on y trouve immédiatement le sens _ivre_ qu'on dit retrouver en français populaire en France, et dans les dialectes d'Anjou, Berry, Bourgogne, Nivernais, Picardie, Saintonge, et en Suisse. Puis la BDL a un [article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=plein&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=2896) entier sur _plein_ avec absolument aucune allusion à ça. Une autre _toast_ ?